# HQL distinct set

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have an entity that contains a set of other entities.

```
class Foo {
    ....
    private Set<Bar> bars = new HashSet<Bar>();
    ....
}

class Bar {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    ....
}
```

Is it possible to do a HQL distinct query to get a list of all the unique Sets?

```
select distinct f.bars from Foo f
```

only returns the distict list of all Foo's

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select distinct elements(f.bars) from Foo f
```